# Relationship with a subclass of SINGLE_TABLE inheritance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I translated some hbm configuration to annotated java class. In the hbm some classes were defined with inheritance strategy "SINGLE_TABLE" and some other entity refer to it with many to one relationship as Map.

when I try to lauch the application I get the following error :
`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Map key property not found: com.package.MyClass.Id`

I searched for some explanation online, but nothing describing at the same time the SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy and the OneToMany behavior in this case.

I have the parent class as follows :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parentclass")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", length = 10, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("100")
public abstract class ParentClass {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "Id", length = 11)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  ....
}
```

the child class :

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public abstract class ChildClass {

  ....
}
```

the class with the relation :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "otherclass")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IdSys")
public class OtherClass extends OtherParent {

  ....

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdOther")
    @MapKey(name = "Id")
    @Where(clause = "type = 2")
    private Map<String, ChildClass> childClassMap;

  ....
}
```

It worked when it was defined in hbm so I guess it should work with annotation.

Comment: is your example complete? I can't see any relationship between OtherClass/OtherParent and ChildClass/ParentClass

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename the map in OtherClass. Now you can see the relationship

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what is going on but I'm having a hard time since this is not a complete example.. there are a lot of missing definitions of members/identifiers: "IdSys", "IdOther", "OtherParent", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out what was the issue.

In hbm file, the MapKey name refer to the column name. But the annotation refer to the field name.

So instead of

```java
@MapKey(name = "Id")
```

I must have

```java
@MapKey(name = "id")
```